# Video card: get Shared system memory and total available memory in c#

Tags: c#, graphics, video-card

How to get the following information: shared system memory, total available memory and system video memory for my graphics card in c sharp?

Comment: You can probably get it through WMI. [See MSDNAA for the appropriate WMI class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394512(v=vs.85).aspx). I can't test today, but I suppose you'll want the `AdapterRAM` and `VideoMemoryType` properties. There's a [WMI tutorial for C# here](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/10/wmi-made-easy-for-c/).

Comment: The AdapterRam gives the Dedicated Video memory and not the Shared system memory or Total available memory. I have already searched in  Win32_VideoController but i have not found anything.

Comment: It might be useful to indicate what you've tried then.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at using [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), specifically the [Win32_VideoController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object. The [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8572) could provide to be useful if you're not very familial with using WMI.