# Total available graphics memory?

Tags: system.management

I know it's possible to get the Dedicated video memory using WMI (AdapterRam) but I can't seem to find anything on WMI to get both shared and total memory for my graphic card ? How it's possible to retrieve this information if wmi doesn't provide them

Comment: @Ghost did you read the question? `AdapterRam` gives the physical amount of RAM. The dupe you linked to says use that and OP already said that doesn't give what they want. The asker wants shared and total.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058378/video-card-get-shared-system-memory-and-total-available-memory-in-c-sharp), [another related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341243/how-can-i-find-the-amount-of-video-ram-installed-through-a-wmi-call)

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/DirectX-Video-Memory-ee7d8319

Comment: @stuartd this gives the value that I already have . AdapterRAM

Comment: @Dablackninja the related questions provide context

Comment: See this : http://i.imgur.com/8szNwys.png , I'm getting the 2gb using AdapterRAM however there is no way to get the other values (Shared memory & Total Available graphics memory) . If I get one of them I will be able to get the other one . with a simple - or + .